# 2 HTML checkboxs with labels to the right, on the same line

Tags: html, checkbox

I am trying to create an HTML display that has 2 checkboxes each with a label to the right, and both on the same line. I also want a heading on the same line eg:

Title, checkbox 1, label 1, checkbox 2, label 2.

All on the same line. So far I have not been able to create this.

I have been able to get a single checkbox and label on the same line, but when I try and add the heading or the second checkbox, it alters the formatting and puts it all on separate lines.

Below is the closest I have come to achieving what I want, but the labels appear above the check boxes, rather than on the same line.

```
<span class="txtSmallGrey fl" style="display:block; width:200px; margin:15px; margin-top:30px"><%= oUtils.GetContentText("Collect_Config_Expense_return") %></span>
            <span style="margin-top:30px">
            <label class="txtSmallGrey fl" style="margin:15px"><input type="checkbox" onclick="fnOnCheck(ER_Enable)" id="ER_Enable" class="fl" style="width:15px; margin-top:30px"/><%= oUtils.GetContentText("Collect_Config_Enable") %></label></span>
            <label class="txtSmallGrey fl" style="margin:15px"><input type="checkbox" onclick="fnOnCheck(ER_Surpress)" id="ER_Surpress" class="fl" style="width:15px; margin-top:30px" /><%= oUtils.GetContentText("Collect_Config_Surpress") %></label></span>
```

I have tried many different combinations, changing the margins, using spans, divs, labels and anything else I can think of. I have also read every post related to the mater I can find, but nothing is giving me a clear explanation of how to achieve my aim.

I know I am missing something in my understanding of HTML, but am not sure how to find the information I need in order to undersatnd how to solve this problem.

Comment: can it overflow? and get a scroll bar?

Comment: @MohitBhasi yes that would be ok

Answer (score 0):

My solution will also work when the text is too big in one of the elements.
Just remove the `display:block` for the title and wrap all the elements in a div

```
<div class = "outer">
//rest of ur code
</div>
```

Its CSS:

```
.outer{
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lcf7jh18/1/

Answer (score -1):

You just need to change display: block with inline-block :

```html
<span class="txtSmallGrey fl" style="display:inline-block; margin:15px; margin-top:30px">
          Title here
          <!-- <%= oUtils.GetContentText("Collect_Config_Expense_return") %> -->
         </span>
            <span style="margin-top:30px">
            <label class="txtSmallGrey fl" style="margin:15px">
             <input type="checkbox" onclick="fnOnCheck(ER_Enable)" id="ER_Enable" class="fl" style="width:15px; margin-top:30px"/>
    Label 1
             <!-- <%= oUtils.GetContentText("Collect_Config_Enable") %> -->
            </label>
            </span>
            <span style="margin-top:30px">
            <label class="txtSmallGrey fl" style="margin:15px">
             <input type="checkbox" onclick="fnOnCheck(ER_Surpress)" id="ER_Surpress" class="fl" style="width:15px; margin-top:30px" />
             Label 2
             <!-- <%= oUtils.GetContentText("Collect_Config_Surpress") %> -->
            </label>
            </span>            
</span>
```

Title here
                 -->
            
            
            
                
                Label 1
                 -->
            
            
            
            
                
                Label 2
                 -->